# Why even use std_logic instead of std_ulogic for implantation purposes?

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I know that `std_logic` is resolved subtype of `std_ulogic` and allows you to drive a signal by multiple sources.

If I understand correctly, designs that contain multiple drivers cannot be implemented even using `std_logic`. so for implementing purposes `std_logic` has no advantage over `std_ulogic`.

when simulating a design including multiple drivers, using `std_ulogic` will arrive you to an error but using `std_logic` is fine and the value of multi-driven signal is determined according to the value of the drivers.

I kind of understand that using a resolved type might have some advantages when you only want to simulate a design, but I don't see any reason to use `std_logic` instead of `std_ulogic` when when implementing a design.

Please correct me if I misunderstood something and can someone explain why `std_logic` used more often?

Comment: The main reason (IMO) is that engineers just got into the habit, and it has stuck. Pre 2008, `std_logic_vector` and `std_ulogic_vector` were distinct types that could not be freely assigned to one another. Hence the easiest way to fix it was to use `std_logic_vector` everywhere, and I guess that just carried over to `std_logic`. 2008 fixed this by making `std_logic_vector` a resolved subtype of `std_ulogic_vector` making it easier to assign one to another, but the damage was already done.

Comment: See [ask]. Your question is both [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [not suitable for this site](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), soliciting opinion and demonstrating no [research effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Explore help topics. Can you craft your question to be on-topic?

Answer (score 0):

The IEEE standard VHDL language reference manual (Std 1076-2008) says:

> **G.2.11 Using STD_ULOGIC vs. STD_LOGIC**
>
> In deciding whether to use the resolved signal or unresolved signal type, a number of considerations need to be made:
>
> a) Does the simulator run slower when using a resolved type than when using an unresolved type, or is the simulator optimized for the STD_LOGIC data types?
> b) How many sources are there for a signal?
>
> Each of these is considered, in order, as follows:
>
> In the absence of other considerations, the choice between an unresolved and a resolved signal type should depend on whether the signal is intended to have only one source, or whether multiple sources are intended. In the former case, a scalar signal should be of type STD_ULOGIC, since inadvertent connection of multiple sources can be detected during analysis or elaboration. Similarly, a vector signal should be of type STD_ULOGIC_VECTOR, for the same reason. In the latter case a scalar signal should be of type STD_LOGIC, and a vector signal should be of type STD_LOGIC_VECTOR.
>
> The same considerations apply to ports, regardless of the actual signals to which they are connected. An input port can be of either an unresolved or a resolved type, as the question of sources is not relevant. An output or bidirectional port with one internal source should be of type STD_ULOGIC or STD_ULOGIC_VECTOR. An output or bidirectional port with multiple internal sources should be of type STD_LOGIC or STD_LOGIC_VECTOR. The values contributed by the internal sources are resolved to determine the value driven by the port. Since STD_LOGIC is a subtype of STD_ULOGIC, ports and signals of these types can be interconnected freely. Similarly, since STD_LOGIC_VECTOR is a subtype of STD_ULOGIC_VECTOR, ports and signals of these vector types can be interconnected freely.

Therefore, it is highly recommended to use `STD_ULOGIC` wherever possible.

The most probable reason behind using `STD_LOGIC` so often is **laziness**. Developers, especially beginners, tend to think less than needed. The second most probable reason is lacking knowledge.

It is the same in other languages. C programs lazily use `int` and `float`, just because it is convenient.

Anyway, your idea to error out early, is correct. However, reality is a different beast, as usual. I would love a warning option to flag unnecessary usages of `STD_LOGIC`.

Comment: Annex G.2 is taken verbatim from the withdrawn IEEE Std 1164-1993 IEEE Standard Multivalue Logic System for VHDL Model Interoperability Annex A. The overview for the 1164 standard tells us "The information annex A is a guide to users and is not part of this standard, but suggests ways in which one might use this package." All annexes to IEEE standards are generally informative and not normative and contains no requirements or directives and aren't suitable for upholding opinions authoritatively. Also see IEEE Std 1076-2008 1.3.4 Front matter, examples, notes, references, and annexes".

Comment: I don't agree with the laziness part. Today still many engineers are forced to code in VHDL'93, because VHDL2008 is "too new" or "not well supported" by some synthesis tools or whatever other reason companies or customers come up with. This matters a lot, e.g. in VHDL'93 all math in numeric_std is defined on the resolved types and not on the unresolved types.

Answer (score 0):

Simple: use `std_logic` when and only when you really want a multiple drive situation. And, contrary to what many digital designers think, this is not just for simulation. Real hardware devices use tri-state buffers, high impedance, pull-up or pull-down resistors, etc. In VHDL `std_logic` and `std_logic_vector` are the types of choice to model, simulate, synthesize such devices.

Look, for instance at sensors like the [DHT11](https://components101.com/sensors/dht11-temperature-sensor) temperature and humidity sensor. It has only one single data line that is used by the controller to send commands to the sensor and by the sensor to send data to the controller. Sometimes the sensor drives the line, sometimes the controller drives the line, and sometimes it is a pull-up resistor (integrated to the sensor module). When modelling, simulating and synthesizing a custom hardware interface with such a device you need `std_logic`, at least for the tri-state buffer that you use to drive the line low when requesting a new acquisition, and to let it float (the `Z` of `std_logic`) when receiving the data from the sensor.

There are other situations where `std_logic` and `std_logic_vector` are needed like, for instance, when designing [SPI interfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Peripheral_Interface) or [I2C interfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%C2%B2C), when working with memories that have one single data bus for reading and writing,...

FPGAs are not the only existing digital hardware targets. In ASIC designs you can perfectly use tri-state logic if you wish. FPGAs sometimes support tri-state logic too (at least in the IO blocks). FPGA synthesizers are not the only synthesis tools. Most ASIC synthesis tools are perfectly capable of inferring tri-state buffers when they see a (correctly modeled) multiple drive design. High impedance and tri-state buffers are not a pure abstraction intended only for simulation, they are real things.

Comment: Leaving ASIC aside for now (because I don't know enough about them). I tried this code for a three-state buffer: T <= '1' when S = '1' else 'Z';. I used T: inout std_logic once. and used T: inout std_ulogic; another time and there was no difference between the implemented hardware in both codes. The only difference was getting an error when simulating with testbench for code that was using std_ulogic;. So if resolved types don't affect the hardware, why we need to use them for 3-state buffers, ...? @Renaud

Comment: You did not model a multiple drive system, just a single drive with a single tri-state buffer (two states in this specific case). It is only when simulating that you introduced a multiple drive with your surrounding testbench, reason why it is only during simulation that you got an error.

Comment: Isn't multi-driving impossible in FPGAs? I looked at a DHT11-controller VHDL code and driving the single line data was like the code I used in previous comment. Can you give an example code of multi-driving that is used for implementation? @Renaud